# Audio Player Displaying Two Players

Tags: mediaelement.js

First I'd like to say this is awesome plugin! I searched high and low and without a doubt you have many other beat hands down.

I have had this plugin installed for over two months and it's been working flawlessly. As of Tuesday the (9/11/2012), the audio player is displaying twice on the pages / posts where I have it installed. I am running the latest version of the WordPress plugin (2.9.1) and have searched the forums but don't see anyone else speaking about this issue.

I have checked in Firefox, IE and Safari, which all yield the same results. However, it does display properly in iOS.

Please follow this link to see the issue:
http://www.senteo.net/michael-ruckman-speaks-about-senteo-on-vegas-profiles-radio-show/

Thank you in advance for you assistance.

Comment: Looked at the pages in Chrome 21 and FF 15 (windows XP) and can only see 1 audio player. There is a Javascript error on this page though. Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'prettyPhoto'